# Variáveis nas URL's amigáveis

Tags: php, get, url-amigável

Como vai?

Estou fazendo o perfil do usuário e existem 3 tabs, ou seja, três áreas pelo qual os usuários podem navegar. Para do perfil, eu reescrevi da seguinte forma no .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ profile.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC]
```

Esse não é o problema, o problema é que eu quero passar variáveis GET da forma normal também, como no exemplo das tabs, ficando algo assima URL:

```
profile/245/user-name?tab=about
```

Mas não lê a variável quando coloco para testar:

```
echo $_GET['tab'];
```

Retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Notice: Undefined index: tab in C:...\profile.php on line 14
```

OBS.: Nas páginas que eu reescrevo que NÃO POSSUEM VARIÁVEIS, ele lê normalmente! Eu até poderia incluir no .htaccess essa variável desse jeito, mas imagina que tenha diversas dessas para coisinhas pequenhas, tipo ?edit=1...

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que você está descartando completamente a *query string* no seu rewrite.

Uma saída é capturar o que vem depois da `?` e incluir no redirect, algo desse tipo:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?\??(.*)?$ profile.php?id=$1&name=$2&$3
                                        grupo 3 ^                adicionado aqui ^
```

Basicamente estou dando uma noção inicial da lógica, precisa levar outros fatores em consideração (por exemplo, pode acontecer de alguém passar um `id` ou `name` e sua aplicação se confundir se não estiver preparada pra isso).

**[Veja funcionando no RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/3dqrb).**  (usei uma barra invertida para escapar as barras normais).

Um jeito melhor ainda é este, postado numa questão vinculada:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?caminho=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

Assim você recebe o caminho todo em `$_GET['caminho']` e pode dividir com um simples explode, gerenciando tantos níveis quanto necessário.

Agora, um comentário pessoal. Essa coisa de converter a tal "URL amigável" em parâmetros de GET, eu acho horrível (mas é como quase todo mundo faz). Algumas aplicações feitas por um pessoal mais "esperto" simplesmente pegam o caminho direto do URL, com `explode` ou coisa do tipo, evitando todos esses problemas. Sugeriria pensar nesta alternativa assim que dominar bem esta parte de redireção.

<sub>O mais incrível é que eu já vi gente ensinando essa simulação de GET em certos cursos de faculdade, mas como é o mesmo pessoal que ensina a usar PHP só com OOP e MVC, não acho estranho o resto.</sub>

Comment: Não funcionou... Já pensei em fazer isso (de adicionar uma terceira variável, mas não é muito efetivo eu acho). Quanto a aplicação acabar 'confundindo', eu que fiquei confundido haha. Como assim? No meu caso, eu sempre valido a URL, faço o link do nome do usuário (com uma função que transforma isso: José Rodrigues, nisso, jose-rodrigues). Nunca tive problemas quanto a isso, mas fiquei preocupado, poderia dar algum exemplo? E quanto a esse outro método, acho que já vi algumas pessoas usando, se puder enviar alguns links de referencia, ficaria agradecido...

Comment: Se não funcionou, precisa revisar o código, pus até uma demonstração no RegExr pra você testar "ao vivo", com uma URL de testes e tudo o mais. Quanto à "efetividade", uma ou dez variáveis não vão mudar a situação. O trabalho do regex é praticamente o mesmo em todos os casos.

Comment: Mude os dados no link de cima, e veja como fica reescrito no painel de baixo: http://www.regexr.com/3dqrb